# Hide certain result based on db with jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have HTML list that looks like :

```
<ul>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something1</li>
  <li>something2</li>
<ul>

<div class="randomwrapper">
   <img src="<?php echo $databaseresult[$i];?>">
   <img src="<?php echo $databaseresult[$i];?>">
   <img src="<?php echo $databaseresult[$i];?>"> // result looks like : ../assets/images/20584878157.jpg
</div>
```

then I have a table that looks like:

[image: table:]

is it possible to create jquery function with ajax that will send f.e.:"something1" to "process.php"(PHP file that I will create in order to process data) which will return the image name (22287895.jpg) and then the jquery function will hide any image that has the "imgname"(22287895.jpg) in it?

i'm able to create process.php but i have no skills with jquery and ajax. I don't even know if its possible.

Thank you for any possible help/references

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "which will return the img name (22287895.jpg) and and then the jquery function will hide image that have the "imgname"(22287895.jpg) in it?"

Comment: What event will trigger the AJAX? i think if you want to hide an image on some event(s) then you can do it even without AJAX.

Comment: Simply put, yes it is possible... what have you tried so far.

Comment: @sunny-soni click on <li> .. i dont want page to reload

Comment: You know to do queries and process the result ?

You could have a button to do the request ( not an ajax ) and the request would be a little bit different.
Don't query for something1 and fetch his image name, but query for name different from something1 so you will get all the images without something1. 

And you will display the result in a GET request.

Comment: @RăducanuIonuţ as i said ... i dont want page to reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right you can do something like this:

```
function getImageName(name){
// do a request that will return the "imgname" from the "name"
}

function hideImage(src){
    let img = document.querySelector(`img[src=${src}]`);

    if(img !== null)
        img.style.display = 'none'; 
}

// then you can do
hideImage(getImage("something1"));
```

Comment: how i do that request ? :D

Comment: @JúliusĽuptovec check this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ . Then tell me if you still have trouble and I'll edit my answer with this part.

Answer (score 1):

**No need of AJAX request**, you have `id` in your DB and `name` (somethings) as well.

Make `li`'s dynamic by fetching `id, name` from DB and then loop through results:

```
<ul class"somethings">
   <?php
   foreach ( $records as $rec ) {
        echo "<li data-recordid=\"{$rec['id']}\">{$rec['name']}</li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

`data-recordid` holds the data ID for each li.

On the image create a dynamic unique id by using `id` from DB like:

```
<img id="image-<?php echo $databaseresult['id'];?>" src="<?php echo $databaseresult['src'];?>">
```

*I will also recommend to fetch all images from your DB*

Rest is jQuery:

```
$(function(){ // checking for DOM to be ready
    $(".somethings li").click(function(){
        var recordid = $(this).data('recordid');
        $("#image-" + recordid).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: for certain reasons it is not possible(in my case) to foreach results :/

i posted just a example. real problem is kinda more complicated